# Barrier after MPI non-blocking call, without bookkeeping?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing, hpc

I'm doing a bunch of `MPI_Iallreduce` non-blocking communications. I've added these `Iallreduce` calls to several different places in my code. Every so often, I want to pause and wait for all the `Iallreduce` calls to finish.

---

**Version 1 with `MPI_Request` bookkeeping -- this works:**

```
MPI_Request requests[];
MPI_Iallreduce(..., requests[0]);
...
MPI_Iallreduce(..., requests[n-1]);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    MPI_Wait(requests[i], ...);
}
```

---

But, I'm working in a pretty big codebase, and I'd rather not write the extra code to keep track of all these `MPI_Request` objects. I'd like to do the following:

**Version 2 without `MPI_Request` bookkeeping -- this segfaults:**

```
MPI_Iallreduce(..., requests[0]);
...
MPI_Iallreduce(..., requests[n-1]);
MPI_Barrier(...); //wait for Iallreduces to finish, without MPI_Request bookkeeping
```

But, the MPI_Barrier version **segfaults**.

---

**Is there a way to do a bunch of non-blocking MPI calls, and then wait for the calls to finish, without keeping track of MPI_Request objects?**

Comment: `MPI_Wait` does more than just wait for the operation to finish, it also frees up internal MPI resources corresponding to the `MPI_Request`. You should generally always use a *bookkeeping* approach and keep track of all pending `MPI_Request`s. See also 
Jeff Squyres presentation on this issue: http://www.slideshare.net/jsquyres/friends-dont-let-friends-leak-mpirequests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how specifically you don't want to "track request objects". Generally, nothing will guarantee that the calls are done other than just waiting for the requests. However, the way you're doing it isn't the simplest way. Instead, use `MPI_WAITALL`.

```
MPI_Iallreduce(..., requests[0]);
...
MPI_Iallreduce(..., requests[n-1]);
MPI_Waitall(n, requests, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
```

This will wait for all of the requests to complete at once and when you're done, you know all of your reductions are finished. If you want to get more fine grained information about how they went, you can replace `MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE` with an array of `MPI_STATUS` objects.

Comment: Furthermore, Waitall seems to match up exactly with the semantics asked in the question: "I want to wait for all of the requests".   I'm kind of surprised the OP knows about non-blocking collectives but not the assorted flavors of completion waiting/testing.